# How to remove freshchat window from other pages in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application

I need to remove fresh chat window from all pages except the home page. I put the script inside the home component mounted part. But once it loads it never closes. If I refresh the page it disappears. I think it's because of the SPA. I think once it loads the JS it does not clear the header script.

```js
mounted() {
    function initFreshChat() {
        window.fcWidget.init({
            token: "***",
            host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com"
        });
    }

    function initialize(i, t) {
        var e;
        i.getElementById(t) ? initFreshChat() : ((e = i.createElement("script")).id = t, e.async = !0, e.src = "https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js", e.onload = initFreshChat, i.head.appendChild(e))
    }

    function initiateCall() {
        initialize(document, "freshchat-js-sdk")
    }
    window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("load", initiateCall, !1) : window.attachEvent("load", initiateCall, !1);
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating functions in mounted instead of methods?, if you want to call it later use in mounted, otherwise you'll always execute that methods on mounted (each time is umount-mount)

Comment: you asking me to put it in methods right? then after that how it should be trigger when user navigate to home page? and it should be remove after navigate to another page. please advise me on this.

Comment: Each component have their own mounted/methods, are you using mounted/method from App.vue instead own component? If that is your scenario please put your App.vue code.

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.fcWidget.destroy();` to unload freshchat. Learn more at https://developers.freshchat.com/web-sdk/ They provide all required events and functions to open and close chatbox.

Comment: I'll try this out. I finish this using customer freshchat button. It also working fine. Thanks for your answe :)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar and added it to the useEffect hook in react, just specifying on each page the argument of true if I wanted it hidden.

```
const addFreshchat = (hiddenOnLoad) => {
  const hideFreshChat = {
    config: {
      headerProperty: {
        hideChatButton: true,
      },
    },
    token: 'your-account-token',
    host: 'https://<freshchatUrl>',
  };

  const showFreshChat = {
    token: 'your-account-token',
    host: 'https://<freshchatUrl>',
  };
  const freshChatConfig = hiddenOnLoad ? hideFreshChat : showFreshChat;

  function initFreshChat() {
    window?.fcWidget?.init(freshChatConfig);
  }

  function initialize(i, t) {
    let e;
    const initiate = i.getElementById(t)
      ? initFreshChat()
      : ((e = i.createElement('script')).id = t, e.async = !0, e.src = 'https://wchat.eu.freshchat.com/js/widget.js', e.onload = initFreshChat, i.head.appendChild(e));
    return initiate;
  }
  function initiateCall() {
    initialize(document, 'freshchat-js-sdk');
  }
  function addSDK() {
    const addListener = window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener('load', initiateCall, !1) : window.attachEvent('load', initiateCall, !1);
    return addListener;
  }
  addSDK();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just integrated fresh chat in my app:

```
window.fcWidget.show() // show widget
window.fcWidget.hide() // hide widget
window.fcWidget.init({
      token: 'your token',
      host: 'host'
    }) // initialize
window.fcWidget.destroy() //destroy
```